# Importing jHipster projects into intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, jhipster

I really would like to start using intellij but I have only used Eclipse. However I just imported the same jHipster project that I have been working on in Eclipse and intellij says I am missing a springboot file. Has anyone ever encountered this issue before? How did you work through the issue?

Now keep in mind I am still learning my way around intellij and I have the ultimate version for free for one year (student version). I am turned on by it for several reasons and want to give it a solid shot.

Event Log:

```
5:39:25 PM Unknown Natures Detected
           Imported projects contain unknown natures:
           org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature
           org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature
           org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature
           org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature
           org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature
           Some settings may be lost after import.
5:39:26 PM Error importing module 'hillcresttooldie': Could not find .springBeans
5:39:34 PM Non-managed pom.xml file found:
           /Users/DrewJocham/Documents/metal/hillcresttooldie/pom.xml
           Add as Maven Project or Disable notification (show balloon)
5:46:11 PM Error running Unnamed: Cannot start process, the working directory /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/bin/MetalApplication does not exist
5:46:17 PM Error running Unnamed: Cannot start process, the working directory /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/bin/MetalApplication does not exist
5:46:32 PM Error running Unnamed: Cannot start process, the working directory /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/bin/MetalApplication does not exist
5:46:33 PM Error running Unnamed: Cannot start process, the working directory /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/bin/MetalApplication does not exist
5:47:13 PM Error running Unnamed: Cannot start process, the working directory /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/bin/MetalApplication does not exist
```

Comment: *"missing a springboot file"*? Is this the exact wording used? Attach a screenshot if possible, or a stack trace/log if it's presented as text.

Comment: @kryger I have added the event log. This is my first time importing a project. I heavily use eclipse but would like to start to get familiar with Intellji. Please excuse my ignorance here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to edit configurations and select the appropriate settings, for me it was spring boot. Make sure you hit the + button to add and new configuration and name it. If it is saying file is not found, click on the event log and select import maven project.